# Tenho um conjunto de checkbox mas só queria um selecionada

Tags: java, android, checkbox

Tenho um conjunto de `checkbox` mas só queria uma selecionada e, se selecionassem outra, a que estava selecionada se desselecionasse.

Já tentei isso, mas não funciona:

```
if (chkfemenino.isChecked()) {
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("genero", generofem));
    chkmasculino.setChecked(false);         
}
if (chkmasculino.isChecked()) {
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("genero", generomasc));
    chkfemenino.setChecked(false);          
}
```

Comment: É simples basta desselecionar quando selecionas a outra. Tem de ser é no `onClick` de cada `checkbox`.

Comment: Ou seja, quando clicas na `chkfemenino` é que pões a `chkmasculino` a `false`.

Comment: Ou use um `RadioButton`.

Comment: sim ja pensei no radiobutton mas tipo preferia mesmo checkboxs.. se fosse possivel..

Comment: A pergunta é válida como conhecimento a respeito de se manipular eventos em checkboxes, mas concordo com o @ramaral: use radiobuttons. O usuário pode ter *preferências diferentes da sua*, mas lembre-se principalmente que os componentes existem para propósitos distintos (capturar apenas uma ou múltiplas escolhas). Assim, há uma padronização de comportamento que é denotada por distinções nos desenhos dos componentes (checkboxes são geralmente quadrados e riscados, radiobuttons são geralmente redondos e preenchidos), que *é esperada pelos usuários*. Mudar isso pode causar confusão nos usuários.

Comment: luis o unico problema eque eu vou querer no meu programa opçoes de multipla escolha e opçoes de so uma escolha e para nao por coisas diferentes eque queria so checkboxs

Comment: Sim, eu entendi. Meu ponto apenas é que ao fazer isso você estará indo contra uma abordagem de interação com o usuário já bem estabelecida, que usa checkboxes para múltiplas escolhas e radiobuttons para escolhas únicas. E, desculpe a sinceridade, mas a motivação pra isso parece ser apenas a sua preferência pessoal. Você pode fazer como preferir (o programa é seu), mas só atente que isso pode causar confusão ou algum desconforto nos seus usuários, desmotivando o uso do programa. :)

Comment: Olha só o tipo de problema de usabilidade/experiência do usuário que não seguir essas convenções pode gerar: http://www.nngroup.com/articles/checkboxes-vs-radio-buttons/

Comment: Só pra mostrar que mesmo a qualidade visual (artística) pode ser trabalhada sem mudar a convenção, mais um link pra você (veja a resposta aceita). :) http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12512/are-round-check-boxes-confusing-or-an-accepted-standard?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É simples basta desselecionar uma `CheckBox` quando selecionas a outra:

```
chkfemenino.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) 
    {
        if (buttonView.isChecked()) 
        {
            ischkfeminino  = isChecked;
            ischkmasculino = false;

            chkfeminino. setChecked(ischkfeminino );
            chkmasculino.setChecked(ischkmasculino);
        }
    }
});
```

E fazes igual para o `chkmasculino`.

Comment: metes isso no oncreate?

Comment: Sim, ou então numa função qualquer, desde que chames essa função no `onCreate`

Comment: ok obrigado jorge b